# Load .js.php file as javascript fails to work properly

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, updates

I have this situation where I load some javascript that also contains some php code. The website is not designed by me so I do not know why the developer did chose this way.

I have to load a file named ***functions.js.php*** and the loading script looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.somewebsite.com/wp-content/themes/theme/js/functions.js.php?ver=1.0'></script>
```

The script ***was working ok up to a WordPress update*** to the last version and also a series of plugins.

I figured out that this is the problem since the console log says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < functions.js.php:1
```

Obviously the first line in that script is some php code.

Also **clicking the script URL will only download the file** and not treat it as php code.

Thank you for your time.

**Update #1**

The php cannot be separated that easy from the js logic since it contains parts of code like this one

```
        <?php if ($dynamic_header) { ?>
            $headerIsDynamic = true;
        <?php } else { ?>
            $headerIsDynamic = false;
        <?php } ?>
```

Full document code is available on this link http://pastebin.com/VkQZwg43

**Update #2**

The script is loaded via ***functions.php*** like this

```
wp_register_script('functions', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js.php', 'jquery', '1.0', TRUE);
```

Comment: can you post the code for functions.js.php?

Comment: @anurupr - please see update for full code

Comment: have you tried running the script separately and see if its outputting the js properly? is the link in the src attribute the actual link or is it a dummy link?

Comment: @anurupr I have tried and it downloads the script apparently instead of actually running it. The link is dummy due to security issues.

Comment: so that's the issue. the php script isn't running and giving the output ( javascript code ) which is why you are getting the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error

Comment: @anurupr exactly! the server does not parse it as php but as something else even though php is enabled and running ok on other scripts (eg: i see the homepage and other content)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47409/discussion-between-anurupr-and-mugur)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a very simple solution did the magic, ***however I do not know why exactly***.

I have renamed ***functions.js.php*** to ***func.php*** and also modified the functions.php script to load the properly named script and it works ok.

***Possible cause:***

the **WP wp_register_script** does parse the filename in the last version and actually parsed the loaded file as a JS only and not as a result of a php routine.

***How to replicate***

Rename your php file from *"filename.php"* to *"filename.js.php"* and use the ***wp_register_script*** to load the file and it will cause the same issue.

Version of Wp used for this is **3.8.1**

Answer (score 0):

this "**functions.js.php**" is a php file not a js file, that´s the error

Could u extract the php logic outside the js file?

Comment: I know what is the difference betwwen js and php, and also I thought of your solution but the file is messy and full of php code. I will update asap the post to see.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your webserver is configured to run php files in the first place; In case of Windows/Apache checkout http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php

Comment: The website works properly. Actually it is on a server and not a windows development machine.

Comment: Then show us the resulting output, i.e. what content do you get when calling: http://www.somewebsite.com/wp-content/themes/theme/js/functions.js.php?ver=1.0

Comment: It does not output anything. It just downloads the file as if there was not php support.

Comment: If this happens I'd be inclined to think my initial assumption is correct; does any other php file get interpreted properly?

Comment: Yes! I see everything ok but this particular script. I also checked .htaccess for special rules but nothing is there. Also the server error log is completely empty.

Comment: Also there is no permission issue since in the wp-admin i can edit the file and save it properly.

Comment: Also check the location of the php file on your server. If other php files are properly produced make a copy of such file and  paste your code in there and see what happens.